# Remaining tasks of Executor Service after timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

When timeout occurs I know that the callable tasks that are currently running on those five threads will be interrupted. What happens to the remaining 10 tasks?

Looks like the remaining tasks are just removed from the internal tasks queue. I cannot find documentation which explains this in detail.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedthreadPoolExecutor(5);
List<Callable> tasks = getTasks(15); // create 15 tasks which takes 2 second each.
service.invokeAll(tasks, 500, TimUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// let's move on.
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Java Doc for `ExecutorService` method `invokeAll()`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks,
                        long timeout,
                        TimeUnit unit)
                      throws InterruptedException
```

Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever happens first. `Future.isDone()` is true for each element of the returned list. ***Upon return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.*** Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

Comment: That's what is unclear "cancelled"; does it mean "remaining tasks will not be executed" or does it mean "We will send cancellation to the tasks - via interrupt mechanism"